# Convert Messy String to CSV Columns

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I have a large list of ids from the Facebook API that I would like to put into a CSV file. Is there a way to parse each ID into an individual column in a CSV file? I am using Python

Current Format:

```
{'media': {'data': [{'id': '17898498243076831'}, {'id': 
'17907011917029111'}, {'id': '17906766215033990'}, {'id': 
'17894813609104671'}, {'id': '17890124843094721'}}
```

But I would like the format to be this:

```
id
17898498243076831
17907011917029111
17906766215033990
17894813609104671
17890124843094721
```

Comment: Use a JSON parsing library (`import json`).

Comment: its a dict inside dict, you can access it with index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED** 
The facebook api seem to be spitting out dictionary inside a dictionary inside a dictionary, well thats makes it easy for developers to do any manipulations with any language. So here is what I will suggest to you

You can do something like this

```
# Create a dictionary 
dictionary_fb= {'media': {'data': [{'id': '17898498243076831'}, {'id': 
'17907011917029111'}, {'id': '17906766215033990'}, {'id': 
'17894813609104671'}, {'id': '17890124843094721'}]}}

# Get the id dictionary_fb and make it into loops
dict_id= dictionary_fb['media']['data']
df =pd.DataFrame(dict_id)
df.to_csv("filename")
```

If you want to do it more often then you can use for loops and get things done

Cheers!

Comment: This is very helpful- thank you. Do you know if there is a way to get more than 24 values at a time?(i.e override the paging:cursors:next?) I would like to get all values in one query

Comment: @Sam I am sorry but I haven't worked on this api so I am not sure how you can fo that!

Comment: That's ok- appreciate the help!